# Umbraco media does not have an approved file type

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco7

I cannot upload anything other than images using TinyMCE in Umbraco Content. I get an error:

> Cannot upload this file, it does not have an approved file type

[image]

I have checked umbracoSettings `disallowedUploadFiles`, there is no `docx` there:

```
<disallowedUploadFiles>
    ashx,aspx,ascx,config,cshtml,vbhtml,asmx,
    air,axd,swf,xml,html,htm,svg,php,htaccess
</disallowedUploadFiles>
```

Also `Developer -> Data Types -> Media Picker` has `Pick only images` disabled. I use Umbraco 7.5.9. I can upload anything using Media section.

It seems like `\Umbraco\Views\common\dialogs\mediapicker.html`

```
        <umb-photo-folder 
            min-height="105"
            min-width="150"
            max-height="250"
            ideal-items-per-row="3"
            on-click="clickHandler"
            ng-model="images"
            images-only="{{onlyImages}}"  <!-- always true -->
            filter-by="searchTerm" />
```

If I manually set it to `false`,  mediapicker would allow me to upload anything but I can't pick non-image files.

Any other ideas on what I should check?

Posted it in Umbraco [issue tracking](http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-9596).

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for posting late. I have just came across an option to allow certain files and stop all other files from uploading in umbraco. Below option is used.

```
<allowedUploadFiles>jpg,xls</allowedUploadFiles>
```

The setting is available at "config\umbracoSettings.config".
If not added, we can add the setting. More information is available in the below link

https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/reference/config/umbracosettings/

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is a bit late, and my issue was todo with Flash (SWF) files. I was trying to add a media type (to no avail, complete newbie).
Then I noticed this post, and removed swf from the umbraco config settings file and it then allowed me to upload.

Comment: Although *of course* I would not want to install any ancient SWF files on a site ;-). (I converted them using FireFox Shumway add-in to play the file, and recorded them with https://tinytake.com/  and saved the resulting mp4).